# Accessing an array of objects without a loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have an SQL query that returns an array of objects called `$results`. The SQL query has a 'LIMIT 1', so there are never multiple instances of an object in the array (no need to loop). The array is below:

> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5875 (1) { ["meta_value"]=>
>   string(3) "yes" } }

The meta_value object can either be 'yes or 'no'. I'd like to access 'meta_value' directly so I can use it's output in a condition, I'm struggling to find a method of doing this though. My code is below, this is not valid PHP however

```
if ($results->meta_value == 'yes') {
  //do something nice
}
```

Comment: $result = $results[0]; and use $result instead $results

Comment: `$results[0]->meta_value == 'yes'`

Comment: Your object is the **first** element in your array. Therefore you can access it by `$results[0]`.

Comment: you could get the result directly from the query to the variable `$result = myQueryFunction()[0];`
then
`if($result->meta_value === 'yes'){...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cause `$results` is **array of objects** you should select first element with index `0` and then take a certain property:

```
if ($results[0]->meta_value == 'yes') {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `array_shift`:

```
/* @var stdClass $result */
$result = array_shift($results);

if ($result->meta_value == 'yes') {
    //do something nice
}
```

For reference, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php.

Answer (score 0):

imo, the easiest, most reliable and safest method of getting the value of the first row of a `PHP array` is to use the [current — Return the current element in an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) function.

```
if (current($results)->meta_value === 'yes') {
  //do something nice
}
```

*Why?*

The issue is that a [PHP array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) is not a 'zero based linear list of cells in memory. It what is really an ordered [hash map](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=hash+map&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=XWp6VvquMsPcaIyMp6AG)
 in other languages.

It is able to use *`any string`* as a *`key`* or `index`. If you don't use a key when you add an entry to the array then it uses a numeric index starting from zero.

The important point is that keys don't have to be sequential integers. They can be words (a string). i.e. *There may be no zero index in the array*

So, how to access the first element of a `PHP array` if we don't know the indexes, which are `keys`?

*PHP Array Iterators*

Every `array` has an `iterator` that is associated with it. The iterator `points` to an element if the array has elements or is undefined for empty arrays.

**When the array is created the iterator is always set to point to the first entry**

*Common Functions for accessing the `Array Iterator`:*

- [current](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) - Return the element pointed to by the `internal pointer` in an array
- [key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) - Fetch the current key from an array
- [next](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) - Advance the internal array pointer of an array
- [reset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php)  - Set the internal pointer of an array to its first element

  *Notes:*
- `current`will return `false` if not pointing at a valid element otherwise it will return the value.

*Summary*

By using the `current` function to access an array you are certain to get the value of an entry whatever the `index` or `key` actually is.